# Allow redefinition of initial bindings for R5RS without using DrRacket

Tags: racket

For the R5RS language, DrRacket has the option to turn `Disallow redefinition of initial bindings` on or off.

This made me curious: Is it possible to adjust language settings like this without using DrRacket? (e.g., when using Racket from the command line, or Emacs)

If so, in which ways? If not, or not in a reasonable manner, why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The parameter `compile-enforce-module-constants` controls whether redefinitions are allowed:

```
soegaard$ ./racket 
Welcome to Racket v6.6.0.3.
-> (compile-enforce-module-constants #f)
-> (module test r5rs (define + -) (display (+ 43 1)) (newline))
-> (require 'test)
42
```

See more here: http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/module-set.html

Comment: Thank you, this does work. However to elaborate a bit further, since this example, as well as those from the docs, take place in the REPL: Is it possible to set those parameters inside a source file itself?

Comment: @bitrauser I believe that's not possible. It is during expansion of the module, the expander looks at the parameter to determine whether redefinitions are allowed. If you place the parameters inside the file, then they will have effect only after expansion has happened. However, you can set the parameter from the command line too: `racket -e "(compile-enforce-module-constants #f)"`.